# Minimum Variance Quantization and MatLab

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, minimum, quantization

I've implemented Minimum Variance Quantization algorithm described [here](https://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/docs/Programming/Graphics/Academic%20Press%20Graphics%20Gems%20Ii%201995.pdf) on page 126 (or 154 if you use pdf viewer search). This method is used in matlab function `rgb2ind` described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) if you specify the number of colors.
However, my implemented algorithm doesn't give the same result as this matlab function. Now I'm trying to explore matlab source code of `rgb2ind`. I found [this page](http://ecco2.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/hyrax/matlab/images/images/rgb2ind.m), by the way, the same information is available from matlab if you print `edit rgb2ind`. There's the following code:

```
...
else % N is given. Use variance minimization quantization
    [map,X] = cq(RGB,m);
    map = double(map) / 255;
    if dith(1)=='d',% Use standalone dither if map is an approximation.
        X = dither(RGB,map);
    end
end
```

Well, looks like the source code of Minimum Variance Quantization algorithm is hidden behind `cq` function.

The problem is that I can't find an implementation of this `cq` function using Google and `edit cq` command in matlab. So I need your help, StackOverFlow community. Thank You!

Comment: Doing a search on Google for `cq.mex MATLAB` came up with the following file. ftp://ecco2.jpl.nasa.gov/matlab/images/images/private/cq.c which seems to be an  implementation of cq from the same reference you gave. In case you don't know a .mex file in MATLAB is a c or c++ implement with bindings for MATLAB. The entry is the mexFunction at the bottom of the file. MATLAB doesn't make their .mex implementations public but this may give the same results as theirs (or they may actually be using this implementation). Hope that helps.

Comment: @jodag thanks, I will check if it works the same :)

Comment: Just about all links on this page are broken...